# apt-get check failed after running sudo apt-get install

Tags: apt, dpkg

I had an error msg from software updater about broken packages which told me to run `sudo apt-get install -f`.
When I did, it ended with another error message   `` `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting… ``
Here’s the whole log, do I have a problem, or need to do anything else?
(System seems to be working, LibreOffice and Firefox run OK)
Thanks for any help or advice.

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS  64-bit
- Gnome 42.5

```
tim@TIMS-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for tim: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for tim: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
tim@TIMS-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Updating database of manual pages ...
man-db.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Setting up nautilus (1:42.6-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
tim@TIMS-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 104 not to upgrade.
tim@TIMS-PC:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libllvm13
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 104 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 101 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 260662 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libflashrom1:amd64 (1.2-5build1) ...
Removing libftdi1-2:amd64 (1.5-5build3) ...
Removing libllvm13:amd64 (1:13.0.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
```